Получение названия месяца bз datepicker
Есть datepicker
<input class="form-control date-text" type="date" id="dateFrom" onchange="displayDateRangeParts()" min="<?php echo date('Y-m-d'); ?>">

который при помощи js
function displayDateRangeParts() {
    const dateFrom = document.getElementById("dateFrom").value;

    if (dateFrom) {
        const [fromYear, fromMonth, fromDay] = dateFrom.split("-");
        document.getElementById("fromDay").innerText = fromDay;
        document.getElementById("fromMonth").innerText = fromMonth;
        document.getElementById("fromYear").innerText = fromYear;
    }
}

подставляет в теги
<span id="fromDay" class="fromDay"></span>
<span id="fromMonth" class="fromMonth"></span>
<span id="fromYear" class="fromYear"></span>

значения, соответственно, день, месяц, год
Вопрос?
Как сделать так, чтобы скрипт вместо порядкового номера месяца, выводил его название, например вместо 1 - январь, вместо 2 - февраль и т.д.
Спасибо.

Получи дату полностью, а потом
date.toLocaleString('default', { month: 'long' });
console.log(month);

